# Why does typescript-eslint show "Unsafe call of an any typed value" when I call delete and update methods

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

```
type TResultCategory<T> = {
  title: string;
  items: T[];
  description?: string;
  delete(dispatch: Dispatch<{}>): void;
  update?(dispatch: Dispatch<{}>, products: TCartProduct[]): void;
}

type TResult = (TResultCategory<TResultProductQueue> | TResultCategory<TCartProduct>)[]

// ...
const [
      unavailableCategoriesQueue,
      updateUnavailableCategoriesQueue
    ] = useState<TResult>([]),

const onContinue = (): void => {
  unavailableCategoriesQueue[0].delete(dispatch); // <= error 
  unavailableCategoriesQueue.slice(1).forEach((category) => {
    category?.update(dispatch, unavailableCategoriesQueue[0]?.items); // <= error
  });
};
//...
```

The UnavailableCategoriesQueue is an array that can have types TResultCategory and TResultCategory, both of which always have a delete method.

Comment: So where is the `unavailableCategoriesQueue` type?

Comment: ① Please tag this with typescript-eslint and react if you need to know about them to answer the question ② Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing; all values and types you mention should be declared, otherwise we'll just get lots of errors unrelated to your question.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen sorry, I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

`TResult` result is an array. you deconstruct that array into 2 const `unavailableCategoriesQueue` and `unavailableCategoriesQueue`. These const now contain `TResultCategory<TResultProductQueue> | TResultCategory<TCartProduct>`. but NOT arrays!

`unavailableCategoriesQueue[0]` now accesses the property with key `0` in this object, which gives `any` as type. `any.delete` also gives `any`, `any.delete()` => `any.any()` is the "unsafe call" from your error message.

Not sure what you are trying to do but at least treat `unavailableCategoriesQueue` as that object that it is, not as an array.